# Materials on 2D Objects Has Bad Lighting and Changes Shape

Tags: unity, 2d, lighting

Whenever I assign a material on an object in 2D unity, it becomes much darker and if the material is assigned to a circle, the circle becomes a dodecagon. The material is completely white. I can fix the color by turning on emission on the material and setting the HDR to white (turns colored objects white, so only works for white objects), but that still doesn't solve the circle turning into a dodecagon.

Image shows unmodified white material added to circle, HDR whited circle, and circle with default sprite color.[image: shows unmodified white material added to circle, HDR whited circle, and circle with default sprite color]
Any ideas to fix this? (by the way doing the whole generate lighting thing doesn't work, I tried it already)

Comment: Did you consider using a transparent unlit material, if you want something that is not shadowed and is able to show a transparent edge around the rim of the circle?

Comment: It also just turns the material completely white.

Comment: Did you mean to choose a material that uses vertex colours, if you want to tint the sprite with the inspector colour swatch?